# How do I upload a new version of an app after an App Transfer?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I know how to transfer an app from one account to another account as I have read the whole procedure for transfering apps from [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html).

However, if I want to upload a new version of the app after transferring I need the bundle identifier to be the same as the previous version of the app. I don't have that same identifier.

How can I upload a new version of that app? Do I need to create a new provisioning profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need the bundle identifier to be the same as the previous version of the app. I don't have that same identifier.

The identifier is transferred along with the app, so once the app is transferred you continue to use the old identifier which has been transferred along with it. Therefore you are free to submit updates as if you were submitting updates to the old app.

> Do I need to create a new provisioning profile?

Yes you will. You can do this from the Member Centre or Xcode as you would have done for the app on the old account.

Comment: I have a question related to it. If I made an app and then transfer it to another account. Then I want to push a update to the app.Shall I follow the below procedure

1. create a distribution certificate in the new account and download it to mac.
2.Create the app store provisioning profile using that certificate.
3. Then try to upload the update.

Comment: @Saty Yes, this is what you do. If you have any problems, feel free to ask a question.

Comment: how can I generate the new certificate. I am trying to create a new app id with same bundle identifier from new account, but it says you can not as the bundle identifier is already occupied. And when I am trying to delete the app id from old account, it is not allowing me by saying, you can not delete the app id as it is in use fo app store.

Comment: @grg So changing bundle identifier is not possible then ? What if I create another app in the transferred account with new bundle identifier?

Comment: @grg Im in the same situation. An app is transfered to our company and we want to update its version.However I cannot see its bundleId in developer portal, how to upload the same app with same bundleId?

Comment: @grg Can u please help me out.